# Qsort to sort array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct, qsort

I am trying to sort an array of structs with qsort. However I am having problems with understanding how to make the compare function. I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
  char name[TEAM_SIZE];
  int points;
} TEAM;
```

And I am trying to sort each team after its points with the highest first.

```
qsort(team, NUMBER_OF_TEAMS, sizeof(team), compare_points);
```

And the compare function:

```
int compare_points(const void *a, const void *b) {
  TEAM *p1 = (TEAM *)a;
  TEAM *p2 = (TEAM *)b;

  if(p1->points < p2->points) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

How would you do this?

Output:

```
Before:FCN 38
Before:FCM 59
Before:OB 46
Before:AGF 37
Before:AAB 50
Before:FCK 71
Before:HOB 18
Before:SDR 62
Before:RFC 47
Before:BIF 54
Before:EFB 30
Before:VFF 40
After:FCM 59
After 8
After:OB 46
After:AGF 37
After:AAB 50
After:FCK 71
After:HOB 18
After:SDR 62
After:RFC 47
After:BIF 54
After:EFB 30
After:VFF 40
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: @EliSadoff It is simply not sorting it as it should. Adding output so you can see.

Comment: Fyi, if you want greater-to-lesser sorting, you need to reverse the logic in your comparator. `qsort` expects a negative result to mean "less", zero to mean equivalence, and positive to mean "greater". And it sorts in *ascending* order. So... tell it a larger LHS is "smaller" than the RHS when it is actually greater and vice-versa, and it should sort in the order you want.

Comment: I would change the second test in the compare function from `else if(p2->points < p1->points)` to `if(p1->points < p2->points)` because a) the `else` is unnecessary and b) you make the same comparison as the first time. Similary the next `else` only clutters the code, because we already left.

Comment: So it's not sorting at all. Can you show the implementation of `qsort` in your code and what is before and after?

Comment: Also, the compare function doesn't need to return just `-1`, `0`, or `1`. You can also just have `return p2->points - p1->points;`

Comment: @EliSadoff no, that's a dangerous shortcut that can fault from integer overflow.

Comment: @WeatherVane Generally yes, but within the context of this problem, it's highly unlikely a team will have a point total anything close to an integer overflow in any sport I've heard of. Especially with the context of the sample cases provided.

Comment: @EliSadoff if you want to use good practice, then use it, not think it won't matter. It is not a good recommendation.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is using `sizeof(team)` instead of `sizeof(TEAM)`?

Comment: @EliSadoff Checking.. two sec

Comment: @EliSadoff was just about to say the same thing.

Comment: @jdoe It's alright. I've made that mistake many times before.

Comment: Yeah don't worry @jdoe, it takes time to get good at this stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `qsort()` call is wrong:

> ```
> qsort(team, NUMBER_OF_TEAMS, sizeof(team), compare_points);
> ```

The third argument must be the size of *each element* of the array.  You are passing instead either the size of the whole array or the size of a pointer, depending on how `team` is declared.  You want:

```
qsort(team, NUMBER_OF_TEAMS, sizeof(TEAM), compare_points);
```

Also, your comparison function is slightly flawed in that it returns -1 when `p1->points == p2->points`.  Inasmuch as you seem to be sorting on the `points` member, your comparison function should return 0 when two teams have the same number of points.

**Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TEAM_SIZE 10

typedef struct {
    char name[TEAM_SIZE];
    int points;
} TEAM;


int compare_points(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const TEAM *p1 = a;
    const TEAM *p2 = b;
    return p2->points < p1->points ? -1 : p1->points < p2->points;
}

int main()
{
    TEAM teams[] =
    {
        { "OB",  46 }, { "AGF", 37 },
        { "AAB", 50 }, { "FCK", 71 },
        { "HOB", 18 }, { "SDR", 62 },
        { "RFC", 47 }, { "BIF", 54 },
        { "EFB", 30 }, { "VFF", 40 }
    };

    size_t NUM_TEAMS = sizeof teams / sizeof *teams;

    qsort(teams, NUM_TEAMS, sizeof(TEAM), compare_points);

    for (size_t i=0; i< NUM_TEAMS; ++i)
        printf("%s : %d\n", teams[i].name, teams[i].points);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
FCK : 71
SDR : 62
BIF : 54
AAB : 50
RFC : 47
OB : 46
VFF : 40
AGF : 37
EFB : 30
HOB : 18
```

[See it live **here**.](http://ideone.com/8P9zuk)